# Reserved Keyword in Enumeration in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-2.0

I would like to use `as` and `is` as members of an enumeration. I know that this is possible in VB.NET to write it like this:

```
Public Enum Test
    [as] = 1
    [is] = 2
End Enum
```

How do I write the equivalent statement in C#?
The following code does not compile:

```
public enum Test
{
    as = 1,
    is = 2
}
```

Comment: By convension, enum values should be pascal case, read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x252001.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Enums with reserved keywords](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688863/c-sharp-enums-with-reserved-keywords) -- Actually the one linked is newer than this one (sorry for the mixup).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Prefixing reserved words in C# is done with @.

```
public enum Test
{
    @as = 1,
    @is = 2
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You will need to prefix them with the @ symbol to use them.  Here is the [msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx) that explains it.

Answer (score 0):

It does seem like a bad idea though - like setting FIVE to equal 6.

Why not just use a predetermined prefix so that te names are unique and future maintainers of your code understand what you are doing?