# C# Enums with reserved keywords

Tags: c#, .net

I'm opening old C# code from my work using Reflector and I found out that there was an `enum` in an SQL class which looked like this:

```
public enum Column
{
     bool,
     ...
}
```

The `enum` is populated with column types and it doesn't compile due it being a reserved keyword. Obviously someone was able to compile it at some point. How do I get it to compile?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you *try* `@bool`?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You need to prefix with a character literal (`@` symbol) in order to use keywords.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx) (Thanks @erikH)

Comment: @erikH I wouldn't say *better* as the other link describes character literals, but I'd say *useful*. Updated to add your link also :) thanks.

Comment: Your link didn't say anything about `@`. From my point of view it didn't relate to the question. But the first section in my contributed link does. That's why it is better, not cause it contains all reserved keywords.

Comment: Actually upon further investigation, it seems your right :). I took mine out and put yours, thanks again.

Comment: in **vb** you need to place the reserved word inside brackets like this `[integer]`. just saying.

Comment: @sharky - props to the inclusive vb crowd ;)

Comment: This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/identifier-names) explains the identifier names.
_The @ is not part of the identifier name_