# C# disable keyword functionality

Tags: c#, enums, keyword

Is there a way in C# to disable keyword's functionality in code? In my case I want to define one of my enum items as ***float*** which obviously makes Visual Studio a bit confused :)

```
public enum ValidationType
{
    email,
    number,
    float,
    range
}
```

Comment: You can usually resolve this by prefixing the keyword with an `@` (e.g. `@float`)

Comment: The naming convention for enums is to use capitals (Email, Number, Float, Range)

Comment: As above, if you use the correct capitals, this issue goes away.

Comment: As freedomn-m says above, if you look at Dennis_E's comment even more above, then that solves the issue

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Enums with reserved keywords](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688863/c-sharp-enums-with-reserved-keywords)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Technically, you can do it like that:

```
public enum ValidationType
{
    email,
    number,
    @float, // note "@" before "float"
    range
}
```

however, even if it's *possible* to use **key words** as ordinal identifiers it's not a *good practice*. Probably a better solution in your case is to *capitalize*:

```
public enum ValidationType
{
    Email,
    Number,
    Float, 
    Range
}
```

Answer (score 6):

No. [Keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx) are predefined, reserved identifiers that have special meanings to the compiler. They cannot be used as identifiers in your program unless they include `@` as a prefix.

For example:

- `@if` is a valid identifier but
- `if` is not because `if` is a keyword.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `@` before reserved keyword like following:

```
public enum ValidationType
{
    email,
    number,
    @float,
    range
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to disable anything, you can simply signal the compiler by using `@` before the keywords name:

```
public enum ValidationType
{
    email,
    number,
    @float,
    range
}
```